# Can a user of an app manipulate objects or variables?

Tags: objective-c, security

Is it possible for someone to manipulate an object or variable, like maybe a high score, simply by having the app (iOS)?  If so, how?  I ask because I would potentially like to hold a contest.

Comment: Users of your app don't have the source code and can't change variable values at runtime.

Comment: Source code is helpful for such things, but *not* necessary. Apple doesn't build in any features for ordinary users to do things like this, but someone with a jailbroken device could certainly attach a debugger and start poking around.

Comment: Suggested protection?

Comment: If you save state to NSUserPreferences, that can be sync'd to a host machine, edited and then sync'd back.

Comment: You can easily do "memory hacking" attacks with jailbroken phone. For example, current game score is 1337. Attacker going to scan whole memory and detect all of addresses that includes 1337. Then start changining values to higher score like 999999. I haven't did this on iOS but I've done this too many times on Android. Ios or android doesnt matter. method is same.